# Incorrect attachment names when e-mail is received in Outlook

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm sending emails with attachments via javax.mail.
MS Outlook is showing attachment names like "ATTxxx.xxx" when there are cyrillic or accented symbols (when there are only standart latin symbols, everything is ok). When I use web interface, names are correct.

Adding attachment:

```
private void attachFile(DataSource source, String attachmentName) 
    throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        filePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        filePart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachmentName, charsetUTF, null));
        filePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        mp.addBodyPart(filePart);
    }
```

I googled a lot, but haven't found any solution.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Rather than encoding the filename yourself, you can set the [`mail.mime.encodefilename`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.encodefilename) property.  You might also need to set the [`mail.mime.encodeparameters`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.encodeparameters) property to false to disable RFC 2231 encoding, which older versions of Outlook don't understand.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is solved. Now I use the latest version of javax.mail - 1.5.0-b01 and everything works. Could you write this as answer?

Comment: The latest is 1.5.6.

Comment: Yes, you are write, it's 1.5.6

Comment: It is not working with version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use the latest version of javax.mail - 1.5.6, thanks to Bill Shannon.

Comment: It is not working with version 1.6.2.